# Making an HTML table of specific width colummns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to made a table in HTML. One column is 85% wide, and the text in it is in  the middle. I believe it is because I have a form bigger than the text in another column. My question is, how do I get the text in the middle to go to the top?

Comment: Sounds like you [shouldn't be using a table](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/) in the first place.

Comment: +1 Thanks Quentin, I was unaware of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the TD :

vertical-align:top